# Activating a window behavior is different when running the app from Visual Studio and directly from the exe

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `MouseEnter` event in which I call `Activate()` to activate the window. The behavior is different when running the app from Visual Studio and when opening the executable.

You can see the difference in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SpPRHFoNLVs).

You can download a demo project where the issue can be reproduced [here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ap7lCHAb5gNEjeoCFGVbgWM-knNhUQ?e=Gr4E0N).

I need the app to behave as it's running from VS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why the behavior is different is because the underlying `Win32` `SetForegroundWindow` function can only bring a window to the foreground under strict circumstances:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setforegroundwindow?redirectedfrom=MSDN#remarks

From the link above:

The system restricts which processes can set the foreground window. A process can set the foreground window only if one of the following conditions is true:

- The process is the foreground process.
- The process was started by the foreground process.
- The process received the last input event.
- There is no foreground process.
- `The process is being debugged.`
- The foreground process is not a Modern Application or the Start Screen.
- The foreground is not locked (see LockSetForegroundWindow).
- The foreground lock time-out has expired (see SPI_GETFOREGROUNDLOCKTIMEOUT in SystemParametersInfo).
- No menus are active.

In your case, debugging in Visual Studio allows the window to become the foreground window.

Running normally, your app doesn't meet one of the items above.

You can partially achieve what you are wanting to do with this:

```
private void Window_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Activate();
    Topmost = true;
    Topmost = false;
}
```

This will bring your window to the front, but it still won't be set as the foreground window until the user actually clicks on it.